# Display numeric values on hover within HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, hover

No code this time around. I've successfully created some graphs in canvas which pull from a mySQL database.

My question is, how would I go about displaying the data values along the graph? Is it possible?

Not looking for anyone to write me code. Just a helpful tip in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really would suggest switching to SVG.

Comment: Never heard of SVG to be candid, could you spare a few minutes for your reasoning?

Comment: SVG allows you to "draw" with actual objects. Canvas is straight pixels. If you want interaction with objects on a Canvas, it's going to require some overhead, whereas with SVG, it's a pretty simple task (you can basically treat SVG elements as DOM elements, and everything that that implies).

Comment: I see, thanks for the info! I'll be making the switch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas to draw text on the canvas itself.

*Or* you can get the x,y positions and used `position: absolute;` DIVs or the like to overlay tooltip like information on top of the canvas.

Edit: Agreed on Shmiddty's comment, this is probably all more a job suited to SVG's strengths. See [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) for a vector graphing polyfill if you are interested.